# what does sho ga nai mean?

Tags: meaning

what does sho ga nai mean? 
Shiran?

Comment: Perhaps the OP probably means [仕様が無い]{しょうがない} (shou ga nai)? This expression is often translated to "It can't be helped" which is not an overly frequent expression in English. I'd be interested in reading a more elaborate explanation from a native speaker.

Comment: Cool, I'll update my answer. It's just hard to tell with romaji as the spaces mean nothing and no context was given.

Comment: Interestingly enough, en.wikipedia has an article on [仕方がない](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shikata_ga_nai).

Comment: There is no salt. 塩がない。笑。

Answer (score 5):

I think that you refer to "shōganai" which is alternative pronunciation of "shiyō ga nai" ([仕様がない](http://tangorin.com/general/%E4%BB%95%E6%A7%98%E3%81%8C%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84)）which means "it can't be helped" or "it's inevitable".

"Shiyōganai" can be interchanged with "shikata ga nai" ([仕方がない](http://tangorin.com/general/%E3%81%97%E3%81%8B%E3%81%9F%E3%81%8C%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84)).

Answer (score 3):

Clearly, it means 生姜{しょうが}ない, *"I have no ginger"*, a common exclamation when one checks the fridge and discovers an absence of that spicy rhizome, indicating a need to go grocery shopping.  For when one has an adequate supply of ginger, all things are possible.

`</oyaji>`

Comment: For any Japanese learners reading this, `oyaji` refers to the expression, [親父ギャグ]{oyaji gyagu}, _"old-man gag"_ or _"stupid joke like what your dad might tell"_.  :)

Comment: oyaji gag best gag

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean "Shō ga nai," which is an alternative spelling of a common Japanese phrase "shikata ga nai" which translates roughly to "there's nothing to be done." It's a phrase which isn't quite so pessimistic as it sounds, though. The phrase is more along the lines of endurance and perseverance in the face of adversity. Presumably this is what was written on the front of the newspapers the day after the Fukushima disaster in 2011. It means, more than anything: we/I will go on.

Answer (score 0):

削がない maybe?

It more or less means to not shave/slice off material, like when sharpening something, or when shaving something like your face or legs, or to not dampen or weaken a mood when used to describe more abstract things, but without context we can't easily tell which is intended.

See the plain negative infliction of this: http://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%9D%E3%81%90

**Update,** it could also be 仕様が無い as G-Cam mentioned, which would be written as 'shyou ga nai' not 'sho ga nai'.

It literally translates to 'The way does not exist', which is the Japanese way of saying 'There is no way' in the sense that something cannot be avoided, it will happen, there's nothing you can do, things like that.

See this expression here:
http://jisho.org/search/%E4%BB%95%E6%A7%98%E3%81%8C%E7%84%A1%E3%81%84

Hope this helps lad. :D